# Applying a function to each quantile of an R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, quantile

I have an R dataframe and I want to apply an estimation function for each of its quantiles. Here's an example with `lm()`:

```
df <- data.frame(Y = sample(100), X1 = sample(100), X2 = sample(100))
estFun <- function(df){lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = df)}
```

If I split that in two subsets on both sides of the median, I manage with two lines:

```
fitsLo <- estFun(df[df$Y < median(df$Y),])
fitsHi <- estFun(df[df$Y > median(df$Y),])
```

However, I would like to find a more general solution where I could arbitrarily choose the number of quantiles and perhaps with `lapply()` form a list of fits.

Comment: May be you need `?cut` with breaks as `?quantile`,that as a grouping column and use one of the aggregating functions.  Try `df$grp <- with(df, cut(Y, breaks=quantile(Y)));
 by(df, df$grp, FUN=estFun)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `findInterval` in combination with `by`;

```
by(df,findInterval(df$Y,quantile(df$Y,c(0.25,0.5,0.75))),estFun)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 df$grp <- with(df, cut(Y, breaks=quantile(Y)))
 by(df, df$grp, FUN=estFun)
```